# Extract part of string from certain position using regex

Tags: regex

String to search for = "in relation to Company A"

Document Contain two lines

```
(a) in relation to Company A, 31 December 2025;
(b) in relation to Company A, Company B, Company C is 31 December 2025;
```

Regex which im trying = `"(?<=in relation to Company A)(.*)"`

But this gives me both lines, I only need first line:

Output Required (means extracting point (a)):

```
31 December 2025
```

I'm struggling with changing regex so that i add date part after the word...

Comment: Several expressions might help, e.g. [`in relation to Company A,\s*(\d+.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/asqhbZ/1/), this requires at least one digit after your needle.

Comment: @Jan - can you add this as answer as it worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given examples you could use

```
in relation to Company A,\s*(\d+[^\n\;]+)
```

and take the first group, see [**the demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/asqhbZ/2).

---

This means

```
in relation to Company A, # "in relation to Company A," literally
\s*                       # 0+ whitespaces
(\d+[^\n\;]+)             # at least one digit + not a newline nor a semicolon
```

In the end use the first group in your programming language/tool.